# What does "-" do in bash (e.g. sort -)

Tags: bash, unix

What does `-` do in bash? Like `sort -` or `uniq -`?

Answer (score 0):

from the man pages of `sort`:

> With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

Comment: Thanks. This then begs the question of what's the difference between sort and sort - when I just do like: cat something | sort ..vs.. cat something | sort -

Comment: According to the man page this doesn't change anything. When I test this it gives the exact same output, so **nothing**.

Comment: thought so. thanks!